# HTML table only loads jQuery half the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to make a stock loader for a Smart Mirror project that I have been doing. The issue I am having is with testing my code. For some reason, when I compile the code, half of the time the table will not load. My coding experience level is "hobbyist" so there is a change I have made a mistake and not known it.

But as the code works for half the time, I have no idea what the issue could be. I have tested it with different versions of jQuery and I still get the same issue.

What am I doing wrong?
Could this be an issue with the JSON Google Finance call being rejected?

```js
var gstock = [{
  "title": "Apple",
  "code": "NASDAQ:AAPL"
}, {
  "title": "Lockheed Martin",
  "code": "NYSE:LMT"
}, {
  "title": "Exxon Mobil",
  "code": "NYSE:XOM"
}, {
  "title": "Bristow",
  "code": "NYSE:BRS"
}, {
  "title": "Boeing",
  "code": "NYSE:BA"
}, {
  "title": "Realty Income",
  "code": "NYSE:O"
}, {
  "title": "Activision Blizzard",
  "code": "NYSE:ATVI"
}, {
  "title": "Level 3 Communication",
  "code": "NYSE:LVLT"
}, {
  "title": "Disney",
  "code": "NYSE:DIS"
}, {
  "title": "Tesla",
  "code": "NYSE:TSLA"
}, {
  "title": "Advanced Micro Devices",
  "code": "NYSE:AMD"
}, {
  "title": "Amazon",
  "code": "NYSE:AMZN"
}, {
  "title": "Raytheon",
  "code": "NYSE:RTN"
}, {
  "title": "Fedex",
  "code": "NYSE:FDX"
}, {
  "title": "Deutsche Bank",
  "code": "NYSE:DB"
}, {
  "title": "Microsoft",
  "code": "NYSE:MSFT"
}, ];

// array to hold previous results...
var results = new Array(gstock.length);

$(document).ready(function() {
  // construct the table...
  for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
    var row =
      "<tr id=\"row_" + i + "\" style=\"height:20px\"><td>" + gstock[i].title + "</td>" +
      "<td id=\"symbol_" + i + "\" style=\"text-align:left\"></td>" +
      "<td id=\"price_" + i + "\" style=\"text-align:right\"></td>" +
      "<td id=\"price_change_" + i + "\" style=\"text-align:right\"></td>" +
      "<td id=\"percent_change_" + i + "\" style=\"text-align:right\"></td></tr>";
    if (i == 0) {
      $('#stocks').append(row);
    } else {
      $('#stocks tr:last').after(row);
    }
  }

  display_table();

  setInterval(function() {
    display_table();
  }, 5000);
});

function load_stock(i) {
  // Need this function so that i can be referenced correctly inside the callback...
  $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + gstock[i].code + "&callback=?", function(response) {
    var stockInfo1 = response[0];

    console.log("here: " + i);
    // update key fields
    $("#symbol_" + i).html(stockInfo1.t);
    $("#price_" + i).html(stockInfo1.l);
    $("#price_change_" + i).html(stockInfo1.c);
    $("#percent_change_" + i).html(stockInfo1.cp);

    $("#percent_change_" + i).append("%");
    $("#symbol_" + i).css({
      "padding-left": "10px"
    });
    $("#percent_change_" + i).css({
      "padding-right": "10px"
    });


    if (stockInfo1.c > 0) {
      $("#percent_change_" + i).css({
        "color": "#70DB70"
      });
      $("#price_change_" + i).css({
        "color": "#70DB70"
      });
      $("#percent_change_" + i).prepend("+");
    } else {
      $("#percent_change_" + i).css({
        "color": "#FF0000"
      });
      $("#price_change_" + i).css({
        "color": "#FF0000"
      });
    }


    if (results.length > 0) {
      // other calculations here...
      // use records[i] to get the previous record
    }

    flash_background("#row_" + i, "#000000", "#000000");
    flash_background("#price_" + i, "#3342FF", "#000000");
    flash_background("#price_change_" + i, "#3342FF", "#000000");
    flash_background("#percent_change_" + i, "#3342FF", "#000000");

    // store the last record (for next time);
    results[i] = stockInfo1;
  });
}

function flash_background(id, col1, col2) {
  $(id).css("background-color", col1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(id).css("background-color", col2);
  }, 300);
}

function display_table() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
    load_stock(i);
  }
}
```

```css
caption {
  width: 25em;
  height: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.container1 {
  height: 20em;
  width: 25em;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container1">
  <table id="stocks">
    <caption>Equities</caption>
  </table>
</div>
```

View on [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Aurum115/21n8j9ya/31/)

Comment: Do you see an errors in your browser console when the table fails to load?

Comment: @showdev After doing the changes that was suggested to change to NASDAQ, there are still errors in the console but they are from too many Google API calls I think. I am thinking of a way to get rid of these currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes your guess is right, the table is missing few rows because some of the listed companies are on NASDAQ, due to which you are getting some failed Google Finance call in your console. just update your JSON and everything will be alright

```js
var gstock = [{"title":"Apple", "code":"NASDAQ:AAPL"}, 
{"title":"Lockheed Martin", "code":"NYSE:LMT"},
{"title":"Exxon Mobil", "code":"NYSE:XOM"},
  {"title":"Bristow", "code":"NYSE:BRS"},
  {"title":"Boeing", "code":"NYSE:BA"},
  {"title":"Realty Income", "code":"NYSE:O"},
  {"title":"Activision Blizzard", "code":"NASDAQ:ATVI"},
  {"title":"Level 3 Communication", "code":"NYSE:LVLT"},
  {"title":"Disney", "code":"NYSE:DIS"},
  {"title":"Tesla", "code":"NASDAQ:TSLA"},
  {"title":"Advanced Micro Devices", "code":"NYSE:AMD"},
  {"title":"Amazon", "code":"NASDAQ:AMZN"},
  {"title":"Raytheon", "code":"NYSE:RTN"},
  {"title":"Fedex", "code":"NYSE:FDX"},
  {"title":"Deutsche Bank", "code":"NYSE:DB"},
  {"title":"Microsoft", "code":"NASDAQ:MSFT"} ];

// array to hold previous results...
var results = new Array(gstock.length);

$(document).ready(function() {
  // construct the table...
  for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
    var row =
      "<tr id=\"row_" + i + "\" style=\"height:20px\"><td>" + gstock[i].title + "</td>" +
      "<td id=\"symbol_" + i + "\" style=\"text-align:left\"></td>" +
      "<td id=\"price_" + i + "\" style=\"text-align:right\"></td>" +
      "<td id=\"price_change_" + i + "\" style=\"text-align:right\"></td>" +
      "<td id=\"percent_change_" + i + "\" style=\"text-align:right\"></td></tr>";
    if (i == 0) {
      $('#stocks').append(row);
    } else {
      $('#stocks tr:last').after(row);
    }
  }

  display_table();

  setInterval(function() {
    display_table();
  }, 5000);
});

function load_stock(i) {
  // Need this function so that i can be referenced correctly inside the callback...
  $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + gstock[i].code + "&callback=?", function(response) {
    var stockInfo1 = response[0];

    // update key fields
    $("#symbol_" + i).html(stockInfo1.t);
    $("#price_" + i).html(stockInfo1.l);
    $("#price_change_" + i).html(stockInfo1.c);
    $("#percent_change_" + i).html(stockInfo1.cp);

    $("#percent_change_" + i).append("%");
    $("#symbol_" + i).css({
      "padding-left": "10px"
    });
    $("#percent_change_" + i).css({
      "padding-right": "10px"
    });


    if (stockInfo1.c > 0) {
      $("#percent_change_" + i).css({
        "color": "#70DB70"
      });
      $("#price_change_" + i).css({
        "color": "#70DB70"
      });
      $("#percent_change_" + i).prepend("+");
    } else {
      $("#percent_change_" + i).css({
        "color": "#FF0000"
      });
      $("#price_change_" + i).css({
        "color": "#FF0000"
      });
    }


    if (results.length > 0) {
      // other calculations here...
      // use records[i] to get the previous record
    }

    flash_background("#row_" + i, "#000000", "#000000");
    flash_background("#price_" + i, "#3342FF", "#000000");
    flash_background("#price_change_" + i, "#3342FF", "#000000");
    flash_background("#percent_change_" + i, "#3342FF", "#000000");

    // store the last record (for next time);
    results[i] = stockInfo1;
  });
}

function flash_background(id, col1, col2) {
  $(id).css("background-color", col1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(id).css("background-color", col2);
  }, 300);
}

function display_table() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
    load_stock(i);
  }
}
```

```css
caption {
  width: 25em;
  height: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.container1 {
  height: 20em;
  width: 25em;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container1">
  <table id="stocks">
    <caption>Equities</caption>
  </table>
</div>
```

fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/21n8j9ya/32/